# customize addNotice message

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using addNotice to display any message on screen. Now, I want to customize it and it should be removed after some time(let's say after 10 seconds) like we can do with javascript.

Is this possible to do this using default addNotice message of magento ?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this script in your page

This will hide the div after 1 second (1000 milliseconds).

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.messages').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds
});
```

If you just want to hide without fading, use hide().

hope this will help you

Comment: where should i write this ? i am using default addNotice to display message.

Comment: add this script in your footer. so it can be available in whole site where you want to disapper notice

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your footer:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var messages = $$('.messages')[0];
   if (messages){
      $(messages).hide();
   }
}, 10000)
```

The code above is the `prototype` version.
If you have jquery already in your website use what @magExp wrote. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Let say your success message id is "success-msg", then write jquery like

```
$(function() {
    // setTimeout() function will be fired after page is loaded
    // it will wait for 5 sec. and then will fire
    // $("#success-msg").hide() function
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#success-msg").hide('blind', {}, 1000)
    }, 5000);
});
```

Remember that you need to load jQuery Library..

Comment: You might want to replace `$` with `jQuery`. Magento already comes with `prototype` that might conflict with `jQuery` if you use `$`

Comment: Yes..I forgot to add that, we need to write no-conflict function..!!Thanks Marius